# wrapping jQuery collection and appending to class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this collection of 21 jQuery elements

> div.article-preview.js-articles-new
>
> div.article-preview.js-articles-new
>
> div.article-preview.js-articles-new
> ...

Using this code I'm appending them to a page. I'm wondering how I can wrap every 3rd element in a `<div class="row">`, and every element in a `<div class="col-sm-12">`. I tried using the jQuery.wrap() function but it didn't do anything to the html that was appended.

```
var newArticles = $('<%= j render partial: "articles/article", collection: @articles %>');

var arts = newArticles.filter('.article-preview');
arts.addClass('js-articles-new');
arts.appendTo($('.js-articles-preview'));
```

Comment: List item elements wrapped in a div are invalid HTML.

Comment: @j08691 thanks, I changed the li's to div's instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('div.article-preview.js-articles-new').wrap('<div class="col-sm-12" />');
var divs = $("div.col-sm-12");
for (var i = 0; i < divs.length; i += 3) {
    divs.slice(i, i + 3).wrapAll('<div class="row" />');
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j7utj0Lf/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try using wrapAll() and [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/)

```
var divs = $("div > div");
for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
  divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
}
```